# Php / HTML / Mysql - Some Error

Tags: php, mysql

When I open **form.php**, **I put the ID**, and after at button **Enviar** say: **Recebeste as moedas.** from obrigado.php

When i check my database, don't add coins.

Some error? Where?

**form.php**

```
   <form method="post" action ="obrigado.php">
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="ebur" name="ebur">

    </textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
    </form>
```

**obrigado.php**

```
<font color="green">Recebeste as moedas.<br>
Atualiza a pagina!</font>
  <?php

    if(isset($_POST['ebur']))
    {
        $ebur = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ebur']);
    $con=mysqli_connect("address","user","password","account");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Falha ao receber moedas, informa o administrador com o codigo 445ebmds. " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE account SET coins=coins +80 WHERE login = '$ebur'");

    mysqli_close($con);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: :( I wan't to know...

Comment: try using `mysqli_error()` after `mysqli_query` to find out what your error is.  Also you may want to use an text input instead of a textarea.

Comment: under mysqli_query line?

Answer (score 0):

According to your `obrigado.php` you will always see a green message "Recebeste as moedas. Atualiza a pagina!", because this fragment

```
<font color="green">Recebeste as moedas.<br>
Atualiza a pagina!</font>
```

is not placed to any conditional operator scope like `if`.

This is difficult to say, if your SQL query has been executed successfully or not.
You need to check result of `mysqli_query()` as NoX answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15276369/301663), and additionally display a success message, if result of execution is okay.

Answer (score 0):

You can check query for errors by this way

```
if(!mysqli_query(.....))
{
    echo 'ERROR: '.mysqli_error($con);
}
```